# Prove the limit $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to {0^ + }} {x^{\sin (x)}} = 1$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Prove the following limit:

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to {0^ + }} {x^{\sin (x)}} = 1$$

I can use limits arithmatic, squeezing principle, "well-known" limits etc..
We didn't learn Lopital law so I can't use it.

I tried to use the above tools, but didn't reach anything significant.
I'm suspecting it's involving trigonometric/logarithmic magic I'm not able to see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** Note that on $(0,1)$, $x^a < x^b$ whenever $a>b$. The adjustment below reflects this. I give a shout out to Baranovskiy for point out this error.

I have an alternative proof. Note that $1 = x^0 \geq x^{\sin(x)} \geq x^x$ in some neighbourhood $(0,\delta)$. What does this tell us? Then squeeze.

Comment: I actually prefer this solution, for it's the conservative one. What do you mean "What does this tell us"? it's telling us we can squeeze :). I guess I should prove there is such neighbourhood. right?

Comment: I guess I was trying to both give and not give away the answer. It never works for some reason, but I don't know why?

Comment: But it's not true. Let's suppose that $\delta < 1$ then in $(0, \delta)$ we have $x^{0} \ge x^{\sin x}$.

Comment: Chris K. You're my man!

Comment: Good proof, actually the $x^x$ part isn't necessary, you can prove directly that $x^{\sin x} < e^x$ by logging and then taking the derivative and showing that it decreases on $[0, \delta]$

Comment: @Baranovskiy, valid point. Fixing proof. +1 Thanks for bringing the error to my attention.

Comment: @ChrisK Now it's OK but still we need to prove that $\lim x^x = 1$ - and that's very similar question to OP's one so we are again at the begining ;).

Comment: Agreed... you're stuck with proving that $\lim \log(x)\cdot x = \lim -x = 0$ by l'Hopital's.

Comment: As I said, I'm not allowed using l'Hopital's law. Should I abandon this solution?

Comment: Well, this is a "well-known" limit and that is why I left it in this form. I am going to fathom a guess that this is what is being asked.

Answer (score 8):

Hint: $x^{\sin x} = e^{x \ln x \cdot \frac{\sin x}{x}}$

Comment: That's fantastic! how did you come up with that idea? I'm really curious

Comment: It is really common strategy for limits of form $f(x)^{g(x)}$ to transform them to $e^{\ln (f(x)) g(x)}$